# Firebird Client - The type or namespace name 'FirebirdSql' could not be found using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, firebird

I've been using the Firebird client since 1.5 and I'm now on 2.6 in my 
Visual Studio 2010 project with .Net 4.0

In my VS2010 Project I removed the reference FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll v2.6

I've installed the Firebird client 5.12.1.0 and then added the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll v5.12.1.0 to the solution.

When trying to build the project I now get and error

> The type or namespace name 'FirebirdSql' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

on every

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
```

I've restarted the Visual Studio and still get errors.

I can uninstall FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 5.12.1 and reinstall 
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 2.6 and (remove old reference and add new reference) the project compiles.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You also should recieve a warning that the FirebirdClient was build with a higher .NETFramework version (v4.5.2) than the one you are using (v4.0). Either use the old FirebirdClient or upgrade your .NETFramework version.

Comment: @waka Might I suggest you post that as an answer?

Comment: Although technically this would be a bug, because I thought .NET 4.0 support would only be dropped with version 6.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot use the FirebirdClient 5.12.1 most likely is because your .NET-Version of 4.0 is not compatible. When trying to use the newest FirebirdClient you should also get a warning, stating that it was build with .NET-Version 4.5.2 and that you need to change the framework version of your project.

So, either install a newer .NET-Framework (4.5.2 or up) or continue to use the older FirebirdClient version 2.6.

EDIT:  I found a better solution on [Firebirds website](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/): Use the NuGet-Package, install it by typing `Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` into the packet-manager console and it will choose the correct package for you.

However, as stated in the comments, you'd need at least NuGet client version 3.6, which doesn't support Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Hi Waka. Im using .net 4 on my VS2010 project. I have tried Firebird Client v 4 - 5.12.1. Which is the latest stable one I can use for .net 4? Thanks

Comment: @Yuppski: I found a better solution on [Firebirds website](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/): Use the NuGet-Package, install it by typing `Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` into the packet-manager console. It will choose the correct package for you. At least it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Waka. I have the NuGet Package Explorer open for the Firebird Client 5.12.1. How/when do I type "Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" ? The Window has File|Edit|View|Content|Tools|Help menus with 2 Panels upderneath. 1 says Package metadata, the othe Package contents.

Comment: @Yuppski: There is a packet manager console (Extras -> NuGet-Packet-Manager -> Packet-Manager-Console [names may vary, I only have the german language pack installed]). If it started up, you'll see a promt like `PM>` and a blinking cursor. That's where you type in the command. :)

Comment: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 5.12.1 requires at least Nuget client 3.6, so your nuget version for 2010 is too old.